# Data Compression in Azure Data Factory via Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

We have a Azure Data Factory Pipeline which executes a simple Data Flow which takes data from **cosmosdb** and sinks in **Data Lake** . As destination **Optimize** logic , we are using **Partition Type** as  **Key** and unique value partition as a cosmosdb **identifier**. The destination **Dataset** also has a **compression type** as **gzip** and **compression level** to **Fastest**

Problem:

The data is partitioned as expected but we do not see the compression on the files created. Is this the expected behavior or is it a bug ? Can some one please help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change your compression level to : **Optimal**
that will take more time to execute but it will guarantee that your files will be compressed in the destination data source.

**as written in Microsoft docs :**

> Level: the compression ratio, which can be Optimal or Fastest.
>
> Fastest: The compression operation should complete as quickly as
> possible, even if the resulting file is not optimally compressed.
>
> Optimal: The compression operation should be optimally compressed,
> even if the operation takes a longer time to complete.

check this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs-legacy